# R: Undefined column error when using mediate in a user made function

Tags: r

I am running a series of mediation analyses using R's `mediation` package. Because the models are extremely similar to each other I wrote a function where all
that would change would be the mediating variable, the outcome variable, and the data set.  The function is below:

```
    library(mediation)
    data("framing", package = "mediation")
    covList <- list("age", "educ", "gender", "income")

    meBrokenFunction <- function(MEDIATOR, OUTCOME, DATA) {

      treatOnMed <- lm(DATA[[MEDIATOR]] ~ treat + age + educ + gender + income, data = DATA)

      medOnOut <- glm(DATA[[OUTCOME]] ~ DATA[[MEDIATOR]] + treat + age + educ + gender + income, data = DATA, family = binomial("probit"))

      expt <- mediate(treatOnMed, medOnOut, sims = 100, 
                      treat = "treat", mediator = MEDIATOR, 
                      covariates = covList, robustSE = TRUE)
      expt
    }  
    set.seed(2019)
    test_first <- meBrokenFunction("emo", "cong_mesg", framing)
```

When I run this function I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(y.data, , mediator) : undefined columns selected
```

However if I run the code without using the function I wrote, everything works as intended.

```
test_treatOnMed <- lm(emo ~ treat + age + educ + gender + income, 
                        data = framing)
test_treatOnOut <- glm(cong_mesg ~ treat + age + educ + gender + income,
                        data = framing, family = binomial("probit"))
test_medOnOut <- glm(cong_mesg ~ emo + treat + age + educ + gender + income,
                        data = framing, family = binomial("probit"))

test_second <- mediate(test_treatOnMed, test_medOnOut, sims = 100, 
                  treat = "treat", mediator = "emo", 
                  covariates = covList, robustSE = TRUE)
```

The error appears to be in the mediate function, specifically at `mediator = MEDIATOR` but I do not understand why it is not working or if I am approaching the problem incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the formula, we may need `paste` instead of `DATA[[MEDIATOR]]`

```
lm(paste(MEDIATOR,  "~ treat + age + educ + gender + income"), data = DATA)
```

Similarly for the `glm`

-fullcode

```
meFixedFunction <- function(MEDIATOR, OUTCOME, DATA) {

      treatOnMed <- lm(paste(MEDIATOR,  
          "~ treat + age + educ + gender + income"), data = DATA)

      medOnOut <- glm(paste(OUTCOME, "~", MEDIATOR,
         "+ treat + age + educ + gender + income"), data = DATA, 
             family = binomial("probit"))

      expt <- mediate(treatOnMed, medOnOut, sims = 100, 
                      treat = "treat", mediator = MEDIATOR, 
                      covariates = covList, robustSE = TRUE)
      expt
    }
```

-testing

```
set.seed(2019)
test_first <- meFixedFunction("emo", "cong_mesg", framing)
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. `paste ()` fixed the problem? Likewise, would you generally recommend using `paste()`  to write functions that contain regressions?

Comment: @Turtlegods  You can also create the formula with `?reformulate`